# Mercurial - Make an unrelated revision a branch of another

Tags: mercurial

[image]

I have been working on a branch, and then decided to merge another branch, so I put my branch under HG, and then pulled in the common base (the base of the two branches) as revision 1, then pulled in the other branch (the one I'm trying to merge) as revision 2.

So after committing revision 2, I had 3 unrelated revisions.  I then merged revision 0 (my branch) with the revision 1 (the base).  Note that if I do a diff of revision 0 and revision 3 there are no differences.

I am now trying to do the exact same thing with revision 2 (the other branch) by merging revision 2 with revision 1 (more specifically, revision 4, revision 4 contains some file renames required due to case handling difference between Windows and Linux).  My problem is however I merge revision 2 with revision 1 (or 4) I cannot get the working directory to look anything like revision 2.  I attempt to merge revision 2 with revision 1, then do a diff, and there isn't a single similarity between revision 2 and the working directory.

How can I merge revision 2 into my working directory and overwrite everything that's already there?  I want the working directory to be a child of revision 1, and be exactly the same as revision 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want the working directory to be a child of revision 1, and be exactly the same as revision 2.

I suggest [hg revert](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Revert). hg update to revision 1, following hg revert to revision 2. Commit to save.